# May a Jewish bus company Pre- sell tickets for a trip to Meron at a discounted price?

Tags: lending-interest-ribbis

May a Jewish bus company offer to sell tickets for a trip to Meron on Lag Baomer before Lag Baomer at a cheaper price than they sell the tickets for on Lag Baomer itself?

Is this a problem of ribbis because the pre-payment is considered a loan (from the buyer to the bus company until the actual trip) and the discount would be a bounus and would be ribbis?

Comment: Goods sold have this issue. Not services rendered.

Comment: I don't see how this is considered a loan. If "Jamazon" (that's short for "Jewish Amazon") offers a 30% discount on *tefillin* boxes for 2 days, and I order it but I don't get it until a day after the sale is over, am I "lending" Jamazon the money? Do I necessarily need to get my purchase immediately at the moment I pay for it? If so, how could hotels, tailors and cleaners be in business?

Comment: @DanF Thank you Dan for your interest. Your question is a very good one. it is for this reason which I asked for answers which are based on knowledge of the laws of ribbis (interest). Halachicaly such a situation is considered a loan, and the cases you presented have specific reasons why they are permitted which would need a lengthly discussion. I'm not sure if the "MODS" allow that here. If they approve I'd be more than happy to teach some of it here.

Comment: @RibbisRabbiAndMore - best it to pose it as a question and then answer it yourself - that gets this important info out into the world in English and educates us.